# Limit a set of processes' CPU and memory usage

Tags: linux, macos, process, resources, limit

Browsing the web has low priority for me, and so I would like all the processes that deal with it to be low priority, too.

Is this approach a valid one?

1. Open a console window with the `nice` command.
2. Launch the browser from this console.

Will the program launched from this console inherit the niceness of the console itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the program launched from this console inherit the niceness of the console itself?

The answer is yes. You can check it `nice -n19 xterm`. In the console, start someprocess, then check the nice level using `ps -efl | grep someprocess`. The nice level is inherited.